# Why sometimes it's very difficult to see the content of variables in Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

[image]

Sometimes it show up sometimes it doesn't

I wonder why.

Comment: What's with the visual space?

Comment: Are you in debug or release mode?

Comment: debug. How do I make sure anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLDB appears to be not as good as GDB at showing the correct state of variables - e.g. sometimes, often near the start of methods, LLDB fails to figure out the type of `self` and you cannot see the instance variables; whereas GDB with the same code is fine.

There are sometimes other reasons; to do with accessing memory, locks, etc.; that a debugger cannot show you variables.

Whether your particular case is LLDB failing or one of those cases when GDB also would fail I cannot say, but if this is hitting you a lot in a particular project switching to GDB might be worth it for the project.